# how to add a toolbar in an clojurescript and react-native app?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, clojurescript

I am currently learning to create mobile apps using `clojurescript`, `react-native` and I would add a toobar in my app. help please

Comment: this is an example of an application using toolbar [link](https://github.com/alwx/luno-react-native)

Comment: Could you show us what you already tried ?